# How do I use my Session variable in an if statement as an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Session that stores an int.  I usually do the following...

```
if(Session["test"] == null)
```

Now that I am comparing...

```
public ActionResult NumbersGame(int myNum)
{
if(Session["test"] != myNum)...
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

(int)Session["test"] will fail if that session variable is either null or not a number. Use this instead...

```
var myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["test"]);
```

myNumber will be 0 if 'test' is null or not a number

Comment: This may sublty cover up an issue that shouldn't be covered up.  If 0 is a valid number you might want that exception thrown (or to explicitly check for null first).

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to an int:

```
if ((int) Session["test"] != myNum) ...
```

Comment: It worked, but now my object reference is not set... what am I missing?

Comment: Just use Convert.ToInt32() as per my answer. Then you don't have to check for null.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of checking and using the value stored in your Session() object involves using the TryParse feature.

```
int intTest;
if (int.TryParse(Session["test"].ToString(), out intTest))
{
   // intTest will have the value in Session["Test"] stored as an integer

}
```

I like it because it's compact and simple.

Comment: This is an awful way of doing it.  Not only do you still have to check for NULL, but you're parsing a string for no reason.

Comment: @ggomez, you're calling .ToString() on Session["test"] that may be null, which will throw an exception, hence you still have to check.  TryParse won't even begin to get called if Session["test"] is null.

Comment: @popester: ur totally right, been bitten by that one alot.. believe me..i still have the scars ;) !

Answer (score 1):

Simple overview of how I would do it:

It may solve other problems too:

First we define interface:

```
public interface ISessionWrapper
{
    int? SomeInteger { get; set; }
}
```

Then we make HttpContext implementation:

```
public class HttpContextSessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
{
    private T GetFromSession<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T) HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    private void SetInSession(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    public int? SomeInteger
    {
        get { return GetFromSession<int?>("SomeInteger"); }
        set { SetInSession("SomeInteger", value); }
    }
}
```

Then we define our base controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ISessionWrapper SessionWrapper { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        SessionWrapper = new HttpContextSessionWrapper();
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
public ActionResult NumbersGame(int myNum)
{           
    if (SessionWrapper.SomeInteger == myNum)
        //Do what you want;
}
```

No need to cast here!! And if you wanted to test your controller, you have no problem with Session. You just Mock ISessionWrapper and pass it to SessionWrapper variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would test for null (to detect Session expiry), then cast:

```
object value = Session["test"];
if (value == null)
{
    // The value is not in Session (e.g. because the session has expired)
    // Deal with this in an application-specific way, e.g. set to a default,
    // reload the Session variable from the database, redirect to a home page, ...
    ...
}
else
{
    myNumber = (int) value;
}
...
```

The problem with using `Convert.ToInt32` is that it will simply return 0 if your session has expired, which may not be desirable depending on your application.